# Playing an audio file on repeat between x hour and y hour?

Tags: audio

We have a RaspberryPi device that we are trying to deploy an audio player in a museum setting.  We would like to program the Pi device to play an auto file between the hours of X and Y on repeat.

This part is simple we can just set a cron job to launch the following command:

```
mpg123 --loop 2 test.mp3
```

But this won't work well if we lose power or the device isn't turned on by the time the job needs to kick-off.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to potentially check and see if the audio is playing and if not kick-off the task again?  Ideally with minimal delay between looping audio.

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: cron job, but that won't power on the device if it is off

Answer (score 1):

`Cron` (better `anacron`) job, or `at` job with re-scheduling, to kick off a script. Script has a loop, plays audio, then checks time and decides if it should loop and continue playing, or if it should stop.

`Anacron` will definitely schedule the job on power-on, even if the job is in the past. `At` should do that, too, but I didn't check.